# How do i load my ASHX CSS handler?

Tags: c#, .net, css, ashx

I want to parse my css code into this conditional css parse (i hope ive said that correctly)
http://www.conditional-css.com/usage

The instructions say that i must paste the c-css.ashx file in the folder where the CSS resides.

Next i must add an @import line in my template master file???

below are the instructions, can you help me out?

> ASHX handler
>
> The C# ASHX version of Conditional-CSS is perfect if you wish to try
>   out Conditional-CSS in a .Net environment, or only have a couple of
>   CSS files on your site. To install:
>
> 1. Place the downloaded file (c-css.ashx) on your server in the same
>      location as your CSS files.
> 2. Load the 'c-css.ashx' file you uploaded in your web-browser and
>          admire the parsed CSS.
> 3. Include the 'c-css.ashx' file as you would any CSS file on your
>          web-pages using: @import "{path_to_}/c-css.ashx"; (or
>      similar).

Answer (score 4):

In your `<head>` section of an html page, an @import is done like so:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
@import "/pathtocss/c-css.ashx";
</style>
```

There's no reason why you couldn't do it with a `<link>` either:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/pathtocss/c-css.ashx">
```